# Swift, Singletons, variables representing functions

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, singleton

Got a strange thing that's tripping me up.  Feels like there's a simple "In Swift 2 we always (or never) do *this*" that I'm missing, but I can't see it.

I have a Brain class, meant to be used as a singleton:

```
class Brain: NSObject {

    static var sharedInstance : Brain?

    var languageLoadedAndReadyFunction = languageLoadedAndReadyImplementation

    init() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: "languageLoadedAndReady",
            name: Notifications.LanguageLoadedAndReady,
            object: nil)
    }

    func languageLoadedAndReadyImplementation() {

        print("Got language Ready notification")
    }

    func languageLoadedAndReady() {

        self.languageLoadedAndReadyFunction(self)()
    }

    class func get() -> Brain! {

        return sharedInstance
    }

    //...

    class func reset() {

        sharedInstance = Brain()        
    }

    deinit() {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

In my unit test for Brain:

```
func testBrainRegisterForNotificationWhenWakingUp() {

    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Function should be called when the notification is received")

    var brain = Brain.get()

    brain.languageLoadedAndReadyFunction = {brain -> () -> () in
        {

            expectation.fulfill()

            Brain.reset() // <-- this sets sharedInstance to a new Brain
        }
    }

    brain.startUp()  // <-- this causes the languageLoadedAndReady event to arrive at the brain

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5) {
        error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

The way I needed to define the function as "brain -> () -> ()" feels cumbersome, but it seems to work a treat.  It let me see when the notification arrived, so I could verify, by test, that we're behaving correctly.  The deinit() method is called after the brain is reset, indicating to me that the old brain is being removed rom memory.

Today, I'm writing some new tests for TranslatorTests.swift:

```
func testTranslatorCanTranslate() {

    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Function should be called when the notification is received2")

    var brain = Brain.get()

    brain.languageLoadedAndReadyFunction = {brain -> () -> () in
        {

            expectation.fulfill()

            Brain.reset()

            print("first TranslatorTests")
        }
    }

    brain.startUp() // <-- 'brain' is different here than in BrainTests.swift, causes
                    // the closure in BrainTests.swift to be called.

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5) {
        error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    translator.setActiveLanguage("en")

    let resultString = translator.translate("about_title")

    XCTAssertEqual(resultString, "About")
}

func testTranslatorCanTranslateSecondWord() {

    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Function should be called when the notification is received3")

    let brain = Brain.get()

    brain.languageLoadedAndReadyFunction = {brain -> () -> () in
        {

            expectation.fulfill()

            Brain.reset()

            print("second TranslatorTests")
        }
    }

    brain.startUp() // <-- 'brain' is different here than in BrainTests.swift, causes
                    // the closure in BrainTests.swift to be called.

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5) {
        error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    translator.setActiveLanguage("en")

    let resultString = translator.translate("actmon_ready")

    XCTAssertEqual(resultString, "Ready to upload")
}
```

When I run the tests, I get the most bizarre error: the closure in BrainTests.swift is called when the TranslatorTests.swift is executed.  This causes the expectation.fulfill() method to be called a second time, causing a crash.

Incidentally, inside the closure there is no 'self' , but if I go up one level in the call stack, the 'self' refers to the previous instance of the brain.  That leads me to belive that the brain -> () -> () syntax is the problem.

This boggles me.  The 'brain' has a different address before each of the closures, which indicates to me that it's a different instance.  In fact, the old brain has been deinited by this point, so how could it be called?

I would have thought that assigning to the variable for an instance would mean that we're giving the closure a new function to execute for this instance.

Can anyone explain this to me?  Please use small words, I'm feeling a little less intelligent than I did when writing this code.

Answer (score 0):

In my research, I stumbled across these two articles that helped:

http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1008188#1008188

That explains to me why the call is "{brain -> () -> () in...".

The problem I had in my code was, of course, that the instance variable was declared like this in my test files:

```
class BrainTests: XCTestCase {

    var brain: Brain!

    override func setUp() {

        super.setUp()
        brain = Brain.get()
    }

    override func tearDown() {

        super.tearDown()
        Brain.reset()
    }

    func testBrainExists() {

        XCTAssertNotNil(brain)
    }
```

So, when I was calling Brain.reset() to drop the old singleton and create a new one, there was still a pointer to the original.

By removing the instance variable, the brain was reset as expected, and the callbacks then worked.  I was able to set callbacks from each test case as needed to pass all my tests.

Goodness, this was a sneaky thing!